# How can we solve halting problem efficiently?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, halting-problem, efficiency

I was doing exercises regarding the halting problem and there is this question where I am stuck

Ques: it goes like suppose if you can decide the halting problem with a query "Is <tm,s> belongs to HALT?" (tm = turning machine and s = string) so it can solve i number of instances <tm1,s1> <tm2,s2> <tm(i),s3(i)> now it says show how can we solve 3 instances with 2 queries only?

I am not sure how to start thinking about this one.. like should we have to simulate one instance with another one? Can anyone provide a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to determine how many of the Turing machines halt. We will show more generally that given $N = 2^n-1$ many Turing machines $T_1,\ldots,T_N$, we can determine which of them halt (on the empty input) using only $n$ calls to an oracle that solves the halting problem.

First, let us see how to determine, using a single oracle call, whether at least $\ell$ of the Turing machines halt. The idea is to construct a Turing machine $S_\ell$ which runs all of $T_1,\ldots,T_N$ in parallel, and halts once $\ell$ of the machines have halted.

Given this, we can determine how many of $T_1,\ldots,T_N$ using binary search. In your case, $N = 3$, this proceeds as follows:

- Determine whether at least two of $T_1,T_2,T_3$ halt.
- If so, determine whether at least three of $T_1,T_2,T_3$ halt.
- Otherwise, determine if at least one of $T_1,T_2,T_3$ halts.

Having found out that exactly $\ell$ of the machines halt, we simply simulate all the machines in parallel until $\ell$ of them halt. The remaining machines will not halt.

It would be interesting to figure out whether this is optimal, that is, whether we can determine the halting of more than $2^n-1$ machines using only $n$ oracle calls.